# Windows authentication across untrusted domains

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, identityserver4, windows-authentication

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web API which implements also an Identity provider using Identity Server. The requirement is to support Windows Authentication via Active Directory, and also Custom credentials.

All these requirements are achievable. An extra requirement is to support Win Auth from different untrusted domains.

Recap:

- Three untrusted domain (A, B, C)
- the ASP.net Core service runs (using HTTP.SYS and not behind IIS) on a server joined to domain A
- a user from domain B wants to login using Windows Authentication (preferable SSO) using domainB\userB

I've googled and it doesn't seem possible.

It's an option to migrate to Kestrel 3.0, but Microsoft says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

> In ASP.NET Core 3.0, Kestrel has the ability to use Negotiate, Kerberos, and NTLM on Windows, Linux, and macOS for Windows domain-joined hosts

so supports only **domain joined hosts**.

My understanding is that LDAP could support untrusted domains, is this true?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure that the concept of "domain" or "realm" is present in core LDAP. But most LDAP implementations also support Kerberos authentication -- which requires that both user and LDAP service belong to the same Kerberos "realm", or to different "realms" which "trust" each other (otherwise you can't get a service ticket with your user TGT). And Active Directory also uses the term "domain" as a bizarre mixup of "network domain" (AD acting as DNS service) and "part of a global, federated forest of Kerberos-enabled LDAP services with mutual trust" -- with also support of legacy NTLM auth.

Comment: Bottom line: with plain LDAP authentication, you just need a login/password for that LDAP server. It's pretty low-grade security, and you **must** use SSL or StartTLS to make sure your password is not transmitted in clear text. And of course, by design, no Single Sign-On (SSO) is possible. SSO requires Kerberos inside a single realm, or multiple realms with trust enabled.

Comment: BTW, core Kerberos does not need _"domain-joined hosts"_. You can use Active Directory as a Kerberos KDC for Linux clients connecting to Linux services, and both client and service will not be aware that their KDC is AD _(all the Microsoft extensions / bloat in the Kerberos tickets will be ignored)_ And the network domains may be different, too. You just need explicit configuration in `/etc/krb5.conf`

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter is this an option for Windows also? I mean having Kerberos auth across different domains?

Comment: AD usually relies on an implicit, hierarchical structure -- e.g. user X from `EUROPE.ACME.COM` can get a service ticket to reach a web service from `APPS.ACME.COM` but the Kerberos client first needs the TGT _(proof of identity as `X@EUROPE.ACME.COM`)_ in its own realm, then it has to hop to the "common ancestor" i.e. `ACME.COM` to finally get access to `APPS.ACME.COM` and obtain its service ticket _(for `HTTP/some.server@APPS.ACME.COM`)_ >> all 3 realms must be defined in the conf

Comment: If you have completely distinct AD domains (or an AD domain and an MIT Kerberos realm), then you must explicitly define the trust relationships in section `[capath]` of the conf. And you must have trust in the first place...